# Close Cookied jQuery UI Dialog With a Link

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm having trouble getting this dialog to respond how I want. The first script works fine but does not use cookies to prevent the dialog from showing for returning visitors. The #closedb is just an anchor that says "I'm not interested" and closes the dialog.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $("#email").dialog ({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal:true,
    width:400,
 });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $("#closedb").click(function () {
 $("#email").dialog('close');
 });
});
```

This block has the cookie check but the anchor does not close the dialog in this example.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
    var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
    document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
    $("#email").dialog ({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal:true,
        width:400,
    });
    }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $("#closedb").click(function () {
 $("#email").dialog('close');
 });
});
```

Here is the markup.

```
<div id="email" style="color: #333; display: none;" title="Title">
   <p>copy goes here</p>
   <form>
     <input type="text" />
     <input type="text" />
     <input type="email" />
     <input type="submit" />
     <a id="closedb" href="#">close</a>
   </form>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help anyone can lend.

Comment: It is working just fine for me. The `#closedb` link closes the dialog, and then it does not appear again (until I delete the cookie). http://jsfiddle.net/losnir/RcLKj/

Comment: Apparently it is working. For some reason only when I am logged into the wordpress system. I'll chalk it up to working for now. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: So the above script works but only when the user is logged in to wordpress. Anyone have experience with such a thing?

Comment: Any errors in the console?